# Odd Bash Error When Running Bash Script In Gnome Scheduler

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to run a bash script in Gnome Scheduler and it refuses to execute a defined variable when run in the program, thought the script runs fine from the terminal.

Here's the error that I get:

```
"date: extra operand '--date=1 hours ago"
```

The command that it's getting hung up on is:

```
LHR=$(date -u +%H --date="1 hours ago")
```

The top of the script reads:

```
#!/bin/bash

SHELL=/bin/bash
export PATH=/mnt/grads:$PATH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compare the output of `type -p date` from your shell and that script?

Comment: When I type the command "type -p date," I get the following:    /bin/date

Comment: In your shell and when the script runs?

Comment: Yes, both in my shell and as output when the script is run via the command "bash hrrr_para.sh" in the terminal.

Comment: Is that the exact error, including the surrounding `"` characters and the single, unterminated `'` character? If so, that seems very dodgy.

Comment: I want to know what it says when Gnome Scheduler runs it. Not when you run it.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of when Gnome Scheduler runs the bash scripts: http://i.imgur.com/x8xNGH6.png

Answer (score 0):

The % charcter must be escaped: \% in crontab entry.

Comment: I don't think he's writing it directly into the `crontab` file, but rather into a separate script file.